# How to quickly copy the current editing file name or full file path in Eclipse (Luna)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This 'solution' doesn't look to work any longer in the Luna version:
[Copy path/file name in Eclipse to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006250/copy-path-file-name-in-eclipse)

This is actually a must have feature for a rich IDE!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [start explorer](http://basti1302.github.io/startexplorer/) ([alternate link](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/startexplorer)) or [Copy path](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/path-tools#.VG2h5IXDGSQ) plugin.
Short cut key to copy path to clipboard in star explorer is : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+
<kbd>C</kbd>

Standard eclipse eclipse doest have such key. You can select resource in Package/Project/Navigator view and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open property dialog and then copy path from here.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I installed the copy path plugin were you simply have those buttons on top. That's just what I needed!!

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these plugins work on the latest Eclipse version, which is 4.14 as of Dec 2019. Any other alternatives?

Comment: Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022313/how-to-quickly-copy-the-current-editing-file-name-or-full-file-path-in-eclipse/59626187#59626187

Answer (score 4):

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

You can right mouse click on the file and select "Copy Qualified Name".

[image]

For this particular example, the path in clipboard is

> /TestingProject/src/com/website/testing/App1.java

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the EasyShell plugin

If using Eclipse 4.14 or later, from Dec 2019 or later, neither [StartExplorer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/startexplorer) nor [Path Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/path-tools) nor [Copy as Path](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/copy-path) works.

**Instead, use [EasyShell](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell), which works great!**

Instructions:

1. Unsure no text or code is selected.
2. Right-click anywhere in your open Eclipse file editor, including on empty space near your code, *or* in the Project Explorer pane.
3. Go to "EasyShell" --> "Copy Full Path to Clipboard", or "Copy Qualified Name to Clipboard" (see screenshot below).
4. You now have the file path copied. Paste it wherever you want.

[image]

#### Totally unrelated aside

Additional note: as far as good Ecliplse plugins go in general, I also highly recommend the [DevStyle](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle) plugin, set to "Dark Gray (Darkest Dark)" Workbench theme, with the DevStyle "Editor theme" (syntax highlighting) set to [Sublime Text 3 (Monokai), by Jeremy Shepherd](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=25808) <-- *Update Feb 2020: dead links. Instead, I've copied and pasted the contents of Jeremy Shepherd's .xml file at the bottom of this answer*.

[image]

**Sublime Text 3 (Monokai) - by Jeremy Shepherd--theme-25808.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<colorTheme id="25808" name="Sublime Text 3 (Monokai)" modified="2014-04-11 19:52:55" author="Jeremy Shepherd">
    <searchResultIndication color="#757575" />
    <filteredSearchResultIndication color="#757575" />
    <occurrenceIndication color="#000000" />
    <writeOccurrenceIndication color="#000000" />
    <findScope color="#111111" />
    <deletionIndication color="#D25252" />
    <sourceHoverBackground color="#000000" />
    <singleLineComment color="#75715E" italic="false" />
    <multiLineComment color="#75715E" italic="false" />
    <commentTaskTag color="#CCDF32" italic="false" underline="true" strikethrough="false" />
    <javadoc color="#76725E" italic="false" />
    <javadocLink color="#76725E" italic="false" underline="true" strikethrough="false" />
    <javadocTag color="#FD2971" italic="false" />
    <javadocKeyword color="#C2BFA6" italic="false" />
    <class color="#56D8F0" bold="false" underline="false" strikethrough="false" />
    <interface color="#D197D9" />
    <method color="#FFFFFF" />
    <methodDeclaration color="#7BE12A" />
    <bracket color="#D8D8D8" />
    <number color="#7FB347" />
    <string color="#E7DD6C" />
    <operator color="#D8D8D8" />
    <keyword color="#F12971" bold="false" />
    <annotation color="#FFFFFF" />
    <staticMethod color="#BED6FF" />
    <localVariable color="#E7F8F2" />
    <localVariableDeclaration color="#F12971" />
    <field color="#7BE12A" />
    <staticField color="#EFC090" />
    <staticFinalField color="#EFC090" />
    <deprecatedMember color="#D25252" underline="false" strikethrough="true" />
    <enum color="#7BE12A" />
    <inheritedMethod color="#BED6FF" />
    <abstractMethod color="#BED6FF" />
    <parameterVariable color="#79ABFF" />
    <typeArgument color="#BFA4A4" />
    <typeParameter color="#BFA4A4" />
    <constant color="#EFB571" />
    <background color="#272822" />
    <currentLine color="#3E3D32" />
    <foreground color="#F8F8F2" />
    <lineNumber color="#72736A" />
    <selectionBackground color="#757575" />
    <selectionForeground color="#D0D0D0" />
</colorTheme>
```

**Sublime Text 3 (Monokai) - by Jeremy Shepherd--theme-25808.epf:**

Too long to post here. See [my dotfiles project to download it](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/eclipse) instead.